# Validate form depending on operations

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, error-handling

I have a form with few input fields and two operations available `Store` and `Validate`. I use `jquery-validation` plugin for client side validation.

In case of `Store` operation only 2 fields are mandatory, in case of `Validate` operation 5 fields. At first when I am trying to do `Validate` operation validation rules work correct. After I am trying to do `Store` operation, but to get it to work I need to clear all the previous errors from `Validate` operation and validate form one more time, with `Store` operation rules. I tried to clear form errors with `resetForm()` , but it's not work correct in my case cause it clears validation error messages only, but the form is still invalid and I can't do any operation until I corrected the errors. Pls share your ideas how to solve this issue.

P.S. code snippet is below.

```
var validationOperMandatoryFields = new Array("field1", "field2", "field3", "field4", "field5");
var storeOperMandatoryFields = new Array("field1", "field2");

$(document).ready(function() {
    var validator = $("#form").validate({
        rules: {
            field1: {
                required: {
                    depends: function () {
                        return isMandatoryForOperation('field1')
                    }
                }
            },
            field2: {
                required: {
                    depends: function () {
                        return isMandatoryForOperation('field2')
                    }
                }
            },
            field3: {
                required: {
                    depends: function () {
                        return isMandatoryForOperation('field3')
                    }
                }
            },

            field4: {
                required: {
                    depends: function () {
                        return isMandatoryForOperation('field4')
                    }
                }
            },

            field5: {
                required: {
                    depends: function () {
                        return isMandatoryForOperation('field5')
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
});

function isMandatoryForOperation(fieldname) {
    var operationName = $("#tempOper").val();
    switch (operationName) {
        case "Store":
            return $.inArray(fieldname, storeOperMandatoryFields) > -1;
            break;
        case "Validate":
            return $.inArray(fieldname, validationOperMandatoryFields) > -1;
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To reset the form completely, you need to do this:

```
validator.resetForm();
$("#form").get(0).reset();
```